# Improve performance for Synchronous SOAP API in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance-testing

I have a `SYNC SOAP` based api in spring boot. There are basically 3 calls based on output of earlier call. We went for calculating number of transactions it can process `tps` and it did not cross even 30 for a load of 5000 transactions sent 100 each second. I am using embedded tomcat container to serve the requests.

I ended up finding below `spring-boot` properties which helped to increase the performance above 40, but still not comparable to 100 transactions being sent each minute.

```
# Core number of threads. Default is 8
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=10

# Maximum allowed number of threads. Default is 1
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=5
```

1. Is there any other spring-boot config which could help to  process multiple request more efficiently ?
2. Can we know how to set these values

Comment: Those numbers won't help. Tomcat has 200 threads by default (assuming that is your container). Measure your application parts and identify the hotspots and optimize. Trying blindly modifying properties won't help getting insight into your applications hotspots.

Comment: yes, Tomcat is our container.